# how to install video/audio plugins using terminal?

Tags: sound, video, plugins

i tried to install using Ubuntu software center but there is problem using it.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe the problem you are having

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the error message is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In order to install video/Audio plugin using the terminal.

enter :-

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Answer (score 0):

When Software center doesn't help try the terminal this is where its true power lies

Install all the ubuntu audio plugins using the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install alsa-oss libasound2 libasound2-plugins padevchooser gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

To know about each package mentioned in the above command follow this link:
[Description of each package mentioned in above command](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/simple-guide-to-sound-solutions-for-hardyintrepid-and-jaunty-jackalope-users.html)